Hotkeys for JSON operations in Pulsar Editor
How to perform the following operations on a JSON in the Pulsar Editor?
https://pulsar-edit.dev/

Collapse entire JSON recursively.
Collapse JSON node one level.
Unfold JSON node one level.
Unfold JSON node recursively.

I have little arrows on the pane on the left to do that but I need hotkeys to do that. Do I need a specific plugin?

Sample JSON:
{
  "question": "Do you want to go outside?",
  "yes": {
    "question": "Is it sunny?",
    "yes": {
      "question": "Do you have sunscreen?",
      "yes": "Enjoy your day at the beach!",
      "no": "Don't forget to bring sunscreen!"
    },
    "no": {
      "question": "Is it raining?",
      "yes": "Better to stay inside and read a book.",
      "no": "It might be a good idea to take a walk!"
    }
  },
  "no": {
    "question": "Do you want to watch a movie?",
    "yes": {
      "question": "Do you have popcorn?",
      "yes": "Great! Enjoy your movie night!",
      "no": "You can always make some quick popcorn!"
    },
    "no": {
      "question": "Do you want to play a game?",
      "yes": "Awesome! Let's have some fun!",
      "no": "Maybe you can relax and take a nap."
    }
  }
}

